# Pushing duplicate objects from one array into their own arrays

Tags: arrays, dictionary, filter, reduce

I have an array of data coming in similar to the following.

```
let arr = [
        {date: "2018-02-02 00:00:00", tabsID: '154', hours: '3'},
        {date: "2018-02-05 00:00:00", tabsID: '29', hours: '5'},
        {date: "2018-02-06 00:00:00", tabsID: '154', hours: '4'},
        {date: "2018-02-06 00:00:00", tabsID: '29', hours: '6'},
        {date: "2018-02-09 00:00:00", tabsID: '154', hours: '9'},
        {date: "2018-02-10 00:00:00", tabsID: '100', hours: '7'},
        {date: "2018-02-10 00:00:00", tabsID: '129', hours: '2'},
        {date: "2018-02-12 00:00:00", tabsID: '100', hours: '3'},
      ]
```

I want to be able to sort through the array and push any objects that have matching dates into their own array like the following

```
let sortedArr = [
        [
          {date: "2018-02-02 00:00:00", tabsID: '154', hours: '3'}
        ],
        [
          {date: "2018-02-05 00:00:00", tabsID: '29', hours: '5'}
        ],
        [
          {date: "2018-02-06 00:00:00", tabsID: '154', hours: '4'},
          {date: "2018-02-06 00:00:00", tabsID: '29', hours: '6'}
        ],
        [
          {date: "2018-02-09 00:00:00", tabsID: '154', hours: '9'}
        ],
        [
          {date: "2018-02-10 00:00:00", tabsID: '100', hours: '7'},
          {date: "2018-02-10 00:00:00", tabsID: '129', hours: '2'},
        ]
        [
          {date: "2018-02-12 00:00:00", tabsID: '100', hours: '3'}
        ],
      ]
```

I've considered doing a map() or reduce() function on the array but honestly don't know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `hashmap` to group arrays by the `date`, and return its set of values as follows:

```js
let arr = [
        {date: "2018-02-02 00:00:00", tabsID: '154', hours: '3'},
        {date: "2018-02-05 00:00:00", tabsID: '29', hours: '5'},
        {date: "2018-02-06 00:00:00", tabsID: '154', hours: '4'},
        {date: "2018-02-06 00:00:00", tabsID: '29', hours: '6'},
        {date: "2018-02-09 00:00:00", tabsID: '154', hours: '9'},
        {date: "2018-02-10 00:00:00", tabsID: '100', hours: '7'},
        {date: "2018-02-10 00:00:00", tabsID: '129', hours: '2'},
        {date: "2018-02-12 00:00:00", tabsID: '100', hours: '3'},
];
console.log( mapDates(arr) );

function mapDates(arr){
     let map = {};
     for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
          if(!map[ arr[i]['date'] ])
               map[ arr[i]['date'] ] = [ arr[i] ];
          else
               map[ arr[i]['date'] ].push(arr[i]);
     }
     return Object.values(map);
}
```